# Energy consumption of a boiler

Tags: thermodynamics, modeling, energy-efficiency, boilers

I have a question that maybe will be very easy for you. 
I am working on a district heating model using Dymola, and now I have to incorporate a boiler into my model, such as [this one](https://simulationresearch.lbl.gov/modelica/releases/latest/help/Buildings_Fluid_Types.html#Buildings.Fluid.Types.EfficiencyCurves).

I was asked to present my results in the form of "energy curve consumption of the boiler" but I do not know how to get it, I have been reading about, but the concept isn't fully in my mind, can anyone help a little here?

Comment: A plot of total input V. desired output ?

Answer (score 2):

Boiler efficiency curves are typically available from the boiler manufacturer, and will typically define the efficiency (ratio of output energy to input energy) as a function of flue gas temperature, return water temperature, loading (as percentage of full load), fuel type or some other operating parameter or combination of parameters.

A good primer for different variables affecting boiler efficiency can be found [here- the Boiler Efficiency Guide from Cleaver-Brooks, a leading boiler manufacturer](http://www.cleaverbrooks.com/reference-center/insights/boiler-efficiency-guide.aspx).